# maxima CAS - how to substitute variable for an expression?

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima, computer-algebra-systems

In maxima, is there a way to apply variable substitutions for a subexpression? For example, replace instances of `x+y` with `z`.

`subst` works for the trivial case, but not for anything more than that.

```
(%i92) subst(x + y = foo, x + y);
(%o93) foo
(%i94) subst(x + y = foo, x + y + z);
(%o95) z + y + x
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `ratsubst` has the effect you want.

```
(%i2) ratsubst(foo, x+y, x+y+z);
(%o2)                               z + foo
```